# Can't Authorize when i try to login to my django project from iphone

Tags: ios, django, iphone, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have created a website using Django (Django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox), ReactJS and redux together. I have run the server from 0.0.0.0:8000 to reach the project from my iPhone and test there. The Website has been loaded however when I try to log in, it can not authorize and gives 401 error. On the other hand, I can authorize without any problem from browsers on PC (chrome, opera, firefox etc.) and android devices.
I have also installed Opera Mini to my iPhone and, again I couldn't authorize it. I don't know which part of my code I have share. I also couldn't find any information about this issue. I would be glad if anyone can help me.